# How to deal with sequence when concatenating SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm dealing with large chunks of data (~50K rows)

I'm concatenating 2 columns for querying, and I want to make so that order of the two concatenated columns do not matter

I.E.

```
Raw data:
item1 | item2 
cat   | dog
dog   | cat
```

```
Query result :
items
catdog
catdog
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some built in functions will help

```
SELECT CONCAT( LEAST(item1, item2), GREATEST(item1, item2) )
```

I guess that is what you want.